# How to add svg images in angular library?

Tags: angular, angular-library

I have created an angular library in which I have .svg images, I have added my images in src/assets/images folder but I try to get image its throwing http://localhost:4200/assets/images/arrow-left.svg 404 (Not Found).
html

```
<img src="assets/images/arrow-left.svg" />
```

Below is my folder structure for angular library

[image]

Comment: Try complete absolute path i.e `basePathURL/assets/images/arrow-left.svg`.

Comment: not working....

Comment: Try print the complete path in console.log and verify what the complete path is?

Comment: Even if I keep the image in the same folder it's not loading

Comment: Try `<img src="./assets/images/arrow-left.svg" />` notice `./` in start.

Comment: If it doesnt work try removing dash from image name i.e `arrow-left.svg` to `arrowLeft.svg`

Comment: it isn't working, this is not in angular project, I'm creating an angular library for publishing an npm package

Comment: Try read [this](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/9852)  then and lemme know if you found something useful.

Answer (score -1):

You should provide a proper image path in your html.

I think your image path will be **./../assets/images/arrow-left.svg**. Try this out.

Comment: this is the relative path ../../assets/images/arrow-left.svg and its not working

Comment: Could you please check your relative path once again?

**./../assets/images/arrow-left.svg**

Comment: that's not the issue, there is some workaround to add assets in the angular library