# Issue with static assets in angular library (png/svg)

Tags: javascript, angular, svg, shared-libraries

I'm in the processs of creating an angular library that contains two static images (.svgs, but I have tried with .png)
The issue is that I'm getting 404 not found on the images, and I have tried almost everything to make it work.
Here's the folder structure:

[image]

Here's a similar problem without answer:
[How to add svg images in angular library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63418882/how-to-add-svg-images-in-angular-library)

Any ideas?

Comment: take a look to this link:https://newbedev.com/include-assets-when-building-angular-library. Another interesting idea can be this another one:https://medium.com/angular-in-depth/how-to-create-a-fully-tree-shakable-icon-library-in-angular-c5488cf9cd76 abot create a library.ts with the icons

Comment: Please don't embed screenshots of text-based content (code, errors, data,...) in your questions or answers on SO.

Answer (score 0):

Try writing src path like this: `../../assets/icons/toggleOn.svg`.